# How to open resizable TinyMCE popup

Tags: tinymce-4

I try to open a popup in tinyMCE, which can be resized by the user (with resize handler and all this fancy stuff).

I've tried multiple settings, but nothing worked.
Has anyone an idea how to accomplish this?

This is my simple code to open a Popup:

```
w = tinyMCE.activeEditor.windowManager.open({
    title: "My html dialog",
    url: '/',
    width: 200,
    height: 200       
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

TinyMCE's native windows have no ability to provide resize handles.  You could build your own HTML page and open it by clicking a toolbar button (or menu option).  As you would (in this case) be in full control of the page you are opening you could make it function however you like.

Comment: Are there any other forms of windows which support resizing or is there any plugin which provides this?

Comment: @Metaphalon you can certainly build your own solution.  I am not sure if anyone else has created their own window manager for TinyMCE but I would be surprised if someone has.

Comment: I hoped there was already something out there, which I could use.
Because the windows already support moving and the js for resizing seemed to work out of the box.
Only the Resize Handler was missing (which is also already available for the editor).

Do you see an easy way to combine all this modules or does this sounds crazy?

Comment: @Metaphalon - its open source software so you can certainly modify it as you need.  Nothing is "crazy" - it just takes time.

Comment: I didn't want to put to much time into this. Is there any possibility to open a popup in a new browser, like it was in tinyMCE 3?

Comment: @Metaphalon- sure.  Create a toolbar button and use JavaScript to open a new browser window.  Then have that window use TinyMCE APIs to insert data back into the editor.